# Ubuntu on VMWare with multiple adapters - can't ping outside

Tags: ubuntu, iproute2, netplan

I've made a machine with 3 nic adapters. Everything works inside configured networks, but It looks like routing is not working correctly:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

Here's my config:

/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml :

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses:
      - 172.16.1.114/16
      match:
          macaddress: 00:50:56:aa:00:1d
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 172.16.1.11
        - 172.16.1.20
        search:
        - domain.com
      set-name: produzione
      routes:
          - to: 0.0.0.0/0
            via: 172.16.1.1
            table: 60
      routing-policy:
          - from: 172.16.1.114
            table: 60
            priority: 300
    ens192:
      addresses:
      - 172.21.2.114/16
      match:
          macaddress: 00:50:56:aa:6f:ed
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 172.16.1.11
        - 172.16.1.20
        search:
        - domain.com
      set-name: qa
      routes:
          - to: 0.0.0.0/0
            via: 172.21.1.1
            table: 61
      routing-policy:
          - from: 172.21.2.114
            table: 61
            priority: 300
    ens224:
      addresses:
      - 172.21.1.114/16
      match:
          macaddress: 00:50:56:aa:16:92
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 172.16.1.11
        - 172.16.1.20
        search:
        - domain.com
      set-name: sviluppo
      routes:
          - to: 0.0.0.0/0
            via: 172.21.1.1
            table: 62
      routing-policy:
          - from: 172.21.1.114
            table: 62
            priority: 300
```

/etc/iproute2/rt_tables.d/swarm.conf :

```
# produzione
60 60
# qa
61 61
# sviluppo
62 62
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot a routing policy for each interface, in order to get to 0.0.0.0:

E.g.:

```
routing-policy:
              - from: 172.16.1.114
                table: 60
              - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                table: 60
```

Here's the full configuration for my case:

```
  network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens160:
          dhcp4: no
          addresses:
          - 172.16.1.114/16
          match:
              macaddress: 00:50:56:aa:00:1d
          nameservers:
            addresses:
            - 172.16.1.11
            - 172.16.1.20
            search:
            - domain.com
          set-name: produzione
          routes:
              - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                via: 172.16.1.1
                table: 60
          routing-policy:
              - from: 172.16.1.114
                table: 60
              - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                table: 60
        ens192:
          dhcp4: no
          addresses:
          - 172.21.2.114/16
          match:
              macaddress: 00:50:56:aa:6f:ed
          nameservers:
            addresses:
            - 172.16.1.11
            - 172.16.1.20
            search:
            - domain.com
          set-name: qa
          routes:
              - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                via: 172.21.1.1
                table: 61
          routing-policy:
              - from: 172.21.2.114
                table: 61
              - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                table: 61
        ens224:
          dhcp4: no
          addresses:
          - 172.21.1.114/16
          match:
              macaddress: 00:50:56:aa:16:92
          nameservers:
            addresses:
            - 172.16.1.11
            - 172.16.1.20
            search:
            - domain.com
          set-name: sviluppo
          routes:
              - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                via: 172.21.1.1
                table: 62
          routing-policy:
              - from: 172.21.1.114
                table: 62
              - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                table: 62
```